# Same command, different results (command line or batch)

Tags: batch-file, escaping, registry, environment-variables, command-prompt

I've been trying to create a very simple windows script which *almost* works ("almost" explains my presence here...). I wanted to chain several commands. One of them is for adding a registry key.
I've found how to do the trick with the following command :

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\DRM" /v "AdminTemplatePath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%LocalAppData^%\Microsoft\DRM\Templates /f
```

I want to add a key named "**AdminTemplatePath**" which has the value "**%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\DRM\Templates**".

Problem is about the environment variable **%LocalAppData%**. When I do the `REG ADD /?`, it says I have to put "**^**" before each "**%**" for the command line to work (without "**^**", the variable would be interpreted and replaced by its absolute value).

When I type the full command in a prompt, everything works fine. I have in the value field "**%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\DRM\Templates**". When I copy/paste this command in my batch file, no problem when running. Systems tells me everything is fine. But actually, the value is "**^\Microsoft\DRM\Templates**" or "**\Microsoft\DRM\Templates**".

When I remove the "**^**" in the full command and try again, value is "**C:\Users\My User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\DRM\Templates**".

Does anybody know the trick to keep the environment variable as is, running the batch file ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^ is suposed to be the escape character in batch script, but I have always had trouble with it too.

Instead, try a double percentage, enclosed in double quotes:

```
^%LocalAppData^%\Microsoft\DRM\Templates
```

Should be

```
"%%LocalAppData%%\Microsoft\DRM\Templates"
```

Check out http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php for more information on escape characters in batch scripts

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. Thanks too for the resource site :)